# Divide specific column(contains) in a dataframe by another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset that I finding probability on. While there are many columns I only have 2 of interest animal and color. I want to count the occurrence of the animal and print the probability of the colors.

```
animal   weight   color
dog      10       white
dog      11       white
cat      18       white
cat      15       black
bird     16       white
bird     11       black
bird     10       white
df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
animal_color=df.groupby('animal').aspiration.value_counts().loc[:,['white','black']]
color=df.animal.value_counts()
```

I would expect the following out put:

```
prob(animal=dog|color=white) = 100.0%
prob(animal=dog|color=black) = 0.00%
prob(animal=cat|color=white) = 50.0%
prob(animal=cat|color=black) = 50.0%
prob(animal=bird|color=white) = 66.67%
prob(animal=bird|color=black) = 33.33%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways

```
df.groupby(['animal']).color.value_counts(normalize=True)
animal  color
bird    white    0.666667
        black    0.333333
cat     black    0.500000
        white    0.500000
dog     white    1.000000
Name: color, dtype: float64

pd.crosstab(df.animal,df.color,normalize='index')
color      black     white
animal                    
bird    0.333333  0.666667
cat     0.500000  0.500000
dog     0.000000  1.000000
```

Comment: thank you for the help.  How would I print "prob" in the front of of each row? Also I want the animal name to print on each row I.E. bird,white,0.66667 and bird,black,0.33333.

Comment: @user11861166`pd.crosstab(df.animal,df.color,normalize='index').stack().reset_index()
`